# pthread_atfork() called more than once causing after fork() functions to be called more than once

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'm implementing a library. I can modify only the files `mylib.c`, `mylib.h` , and not the `main()` which inside another file.

When a process inside main() calls `mylib_init()` then can start using `mylib.h, mylib.c` functions.

When a process calls `mylib_exit()` he can no longer use `mylib.h, mylib.c` functions.

I want to count the number of processes currently using `mylib` library, so inside `mylib_init()` there is a

`pthread_atfork(my_prepare_fork, NULL, NULL);`

```
my_prepare_fork() {
    p_using_mylib ++;
}
```

(While `p_using_mylib` implemented by shared memory, and there are semaphores and everything that should be included...)

I encountered a problem in the next occurence:

Pseudo code of a given main() function:

1. father calls `mylib_init()`
2. father calls `mylib_exit()`
3. father calls `mylib_init()` //second time
4. father do `fork()`

Because `mylib_init()` called twice, `pthread_atfork()` also called twice, and because of that now at `fork()`, the function `my_prepare_fork()` is called twice.
=> number of `p_using_mylib` will be incorrect, and this is the problem.

So I wanted to know:

1. Is there any way to unregister the `pthread_atfork()` that was before?
2. Is there any way of registering a function, only to the first time the main process is borned ? In a situation like that, I could put in this function the initialization of `pthread_atfork()`
3. Is there another way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not decrement `p_using_mylib` in `mylib_exit()`?

Comment: Cause I should decrement when a process stop using the library with `mylib_exit()`, not when the process dies (he can live, and not using the library - and I should see that as '0' processes using the library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "unregister" `pthread_atfork` functions. You should be using `pthread_once` to protect all initialization-type routines from being run more than once.